# Strongswan transport mode ipsec within subnet

Tags: linux, ipsec, strongswan

Is there any way to configure strongswan to automatically start encryption to a given subnet rather than specific host? For example, if I know that my hosts at `w.x.y.z/28` will be have the same PSK configured. I'd like to configure all of them in one go with:

```
conn protected
    left=%any
    right=%any
    rightsubnet=w.x.y.z/28
    auto=route
    forceencaps=no
    type=transport
    mobike=no
    authby=psk
```

or similar. I want to avoid specifying each one separately. I expected the trap on routes to do the required startup as needed. But strongswan refuses to work this way and claims that `installing trap failed, remote address unknown`.

Is this scenario possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Strongswan 5.3.3 or later.

See the test case trap-any in https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/tree/master/testing/tests/ikev2/trap-any

See also Strongswan issues  https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/878 and https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/196

Hope this helps